# iOS7: Navigation Bar and Tab Bar transparency looks different on a real iDevice

Tags: iphone, ios7, tabbar, xcode5, navigationbar

I'm currently developing an app for iOS7, using XCode5.
Today was my first attempt to test the app on a real device (iPhone 4 with iOS7.0).
I've noticed there is a difference between what I see in the simulator and what I see on the real device.
The Navigation Bar and Tab Bar are defined as follows:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];

[self.tabBarController.tabBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

The level of transparency is very different between the simulator and the real device, as can be seen in the screenshots below:
1.Screenshot from Simulator:

[image]

2.Screenshot from a real iPhone:

[image]

I can't find anything about that online. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: @TonyMkenu Thanks for the reply. If you looks closer you will notice the real device just darker in that area, but it's still transparent.
Please note, at the moment the Bars don't have any background color set. But if I set color and color alpha then it looks better on the iDevice, but in the Simulator it looks BAD. lol

Answer (score 0):

sorry for poor english .. I'm using google translator.

I was having this same problem, but in colors of the buttons in the tabbar and navigationBar. I found that this is a configuration of iOS. On your device go to Settings> General> Accessibility> Increase Contrast.

It remains now to discover how to predict whether the user is modified with these settings and make adjustments via code.